# Formatted output from numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, format

I have two (numpy) arrays that I want to write to file. The first is a 1-d array with integers of length n, the second is a 2-d array with the dimensions nx3. The output should be formatted according to (I8,TR5,3E14.6) TR5 = insert 5 whitespaces. I could do it with a loop over all n elements, but that doesn't feel pythonic. I have tried with numpy.savetxt(). It works nice with just the 2-d array, but I can't get my head around how to include the integer and blanks. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np

fout = "outfile.txt"

coord = np.array([[0.0,0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0,2.0]],float)
nodnr = np.array([[1,2,3]],int)

np.savetxt(fout,coord,delimiter=" ",fmt="%14.6E")
```

The output should look like this:

```
       1      0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00   0.000000E+00
       2      1.000000E+00   1.000000E+00   1.000000E+00
       3      2.000000E+00   2.000000E+00   2.000000E+00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two arrays into one array of dtype `float`

```
arr = np.column_stack([nodnr.T, coord])
```

Then call `np.savetxt` with a [multi-format string](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import numpy as np

fout = "outfile.txt"

coord = np.array([[0.0,0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0,2.0]],float)
nodnr = np.array([[1,2,3]],int)
arr = np.column_stack([nodnr.T, coord])
np.savetxt(fout, arr, 
           fmt='{}{}{}'.format('%d', ' '*5, ' '.join(['%14.6E']*coord.shape[1])))
```

yields

```
1       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
2       1.000000E+00       1.000000E+00       1.000000E+00
3       2.000000E+00       2.000000E+00       2.000000E+00
```

Comment: Thx, that sorted (most of) it. The TR5 should only be added once, between the integer and the first float. Should I print a 5-whietspace long string there? Btw, what does nodnr.T mean?

Comment: In that case, you could use a multi-format string instead of a list of formats (see edit, above). `nodnr.T` is the transpose of `nodnr`. Since `nodnr.shape` is `(1, 3)`, it is a 2-dimensional array with one row and three columns. To *column-stack* it with `coord`, we need to make it a 2D array with three rows and one column. That's what the transpose does.

Comment: Thx x2, now I got it :)